# How to parse XML using PHP no code?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am learning how to parse in various languages. Right now I am trying to learn PHP. Can anyone help get me started?

http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml

is the page I would like to parse using PHP. Is this possible and how do you do it with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $xml=simplexml_load_file('http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml');
  print_r($xml);
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: You can use the url directly in `simplexml_load_file()` if the fopen wrappers are enabled

Answer (score 0):

Simple XML is good if you need a DOM interface to the XML, but if you need something quick just to go from XML into an associative array there's a great utility script that's super simple online:

http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/

I've only used it for internal xml files, so its worth a security audit if you're using external xml

Answer (score 0):

simplexml_load_file() is really a good start for this.
note here, $xml is not an array. if you want to save more records in your database, use it in a proper way.
print_r($xml) will help you to get the better structure .